# What is getSeekableFileDescriptor() in this android doc?

Tags: java, android, file

I am playing with Android 4.4 PDF renderer and do not understnad what getSeekableFileDescriptor() is.

```
PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some of Google's code snippets use placeholders for methods providing data required by the sample.

In this case, `getSeekableFileDescriptor()` needs to return a `ParcelFileDescriptor` that `PdfRenderer` can use. In particular, it needs to be "seekable", meaning that a stream opened on the `ParcelFileDescriptor` needs to be one that can be seeked forwards and backwards. For example, the static `open()` method on `ParcelFileDescriptor` gives you a seekable descriptor; `createPipe()` does not.